# Looking for value of equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been trying to solve this MONBUKAGAKUSHO past test papers, and I am completely stuck. I have no single idea how to solve it, and I´ve tried many different things, but without any results. Here is the link: 
http://www.studyjapan.go.jp/pdf/questions/10/ga-math_a.pdf 
The question is as follows:

We are to find the value of $x^4 + y^4 + z^4$, when $x,y$ and $z$ are real numbers which satisfy the following three equalities:
$$\begin{cases} x + y + z = 3\\
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9\\
xyz = -2\end{cases}$$

Firstly, it follows from the first two equalities that 
$xy + yz + zx = A$

Next using

$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 = x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + B((xy)^2 + (yz)^2 + (zx)^2)$

we have

$x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = C$

Comment: Which one of the 7 questions in your link is this?

Comment: I´m really sorry, I´ve accidently put a different link (for the different version)  in the description, but it should be ok now. It is the Question 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given the following three relations:

$$x + y + z = 3$$
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9$$
$$xyz = -2$$

Take the square of eq (1), subtract from this eq (2) and divide by 2. This yields:

$$xy + yz + zx = 0$$

Squaring this equation yields:

$$(xy)^2 + (yz)^2 + (zx)^2 + 2xyz(x + y + z) = 0$$

With the help of equations (1) and (3) this can be simplified:

$$(xy)^2 + (yz)^2 + (zx)^2 = 12$$

Now squaring the second equation yields:

$$x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + 2(xy)^2 + 2(yz)^2 + 2(zx)^2 = 81$$

Substituting the result of the previous equation leads to the final result:

$$x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = 57$$

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! It was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given $$x+y+z = 3\;\;,x^2+y^2+z^2=9\;\;,xyz=-2$$

Now Using $$(x+y+z)^2= x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)\Rightarrow (xy+yz+zx) = 0$$

Now Let $$t=x\;,t=y\;,t=z$$ are the roots of a cubic equation in terms of variable $t\;,$ Then

Using factor Theorem $$(t-x)\;\;,(t-y)\;\;, (t-z)$$ are the roots of given equation.

So we can write $$(t-x)\cdot (t-y)\cdot (t-z) = 0\Rightarrow t^3-(x+y+z)t^2+(xy+yz+zx)t-xyz=0$$

So  we get $$t^3-3t^2+2=0\Rightarrow t^4-3t^3+2t=0$$

So $$\displaystyle \sum x^4-3\sum x^3+2\sum x = 0...............................(\star)$$

Where $$\displaystyle \sum x^r=x^r+y^r+z^r$$

Now Using $$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz = (x+y+z)\cdot (x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$$

We get $$\displaystyle \sum x^3+6=3\cdot 9\Rightarrow \sum x^3 = 21$$

Now put that value in $.............................(\star)$

We get $$\displaystyle \sum x^4-3\cdot 21+2\cdot 3 = 0\Rightarrow \sum x^4=57$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I´ve never thought this could have so many different ways of solving it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

1. As *polynomials*, what's $(a+b+c)^2-a^2-b^2-c^2$? How can you use this to calculate $A$?
2. The value of $B$ *will* turn out to be independent of the fact that $x,y,z$ solve that particular system... Maybe the previous effort in calculating the square of a trinomial will be useful.
3. check that
   $$ (xy+yz+xz)^2=(xy)^2+(yz)^2+(zx)^2+2xyz(x+y+z) $$
   And, if you already have $A$ and $B$, you should have all the pieces to find $C$ thanks to the tools provided by the system of equalities.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will never forget your kindness!
Actually, I am a huge mathematical dummy, but I really want to study in Japan so I have to pass this test. When I´ve seen the past papers for the first time, I´ve almost fainted. However, I still have two years to prepare for the test, so I must give it everything. 
The fact that I couldn´t solve any problem was so depressing, I wasn´t sleeping very well and I´ve been constantly thinking about possible ways of solving at least one. I can´t even express the gratitude in words, but once again - thank you from the bottom of my heart!